# Modifying the link script cannot modify the starting address of the assembly

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, riscv

Recently, I was doing functional testing of riscv cpu cores. When I tested the ISA instruction set, I found that the RVC compression instruction test assembly is not under the control of the linker.

Examples are as follows.

If the starting address in the link script is 0x00, the RVC disassembly (dump) file will show that the starting address of the RVC compression instruction is 0x00. However, if the starting address in the link script is replaced with any address, the RVC The starting address of the compressed instruction test code will start from 0x00001000.

The contents of the link script file are as follows.

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x80;  /*Any address other than 0x00 is fine*/
  .text : {KEEP(*(.text)) }
}
```

The contents of the dump file are as follows.

```
../tests/isa/rv32uc/rvc.elf:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <_start>:

#include "riscv_test.h"
#include "test_macros.h"

RVTEST_RV64U
RVTEST_CODE_BEGIN
    1000:   a009                    j   1002 <_start_main>

00001002 <_start_main>:
    1002:   0001                    nop
......
```

This starting address does not seem to be controlled by the link script, why is this???

The disassembly file of the same link script to test the add instruction is as follows.

```
../tests/isa/rv32ui/add.elf:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

00000080 <_start>:

#include "riscv_test.h"
#include "test_macros.h"

RVTEST_RV64U
RVTEST_CODE_BEGIN
  80:   a009                    j   82 <_start_main>

00000082 <_start_main>:
......
```

Use add to test the starting address is 0x80, this is correct, why the RVC compression instruction does not work, this really puzzles me！

Please point me if anyone knows this, thanks a lot!！

（English is not my native language, please forgive me if there are grammatical errors）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved, mainly because the align indicator in the rvc file limits the minimum address allocation unit, so the rvc start address is fixed from 0x1000 (0x1000 is the minimum address allocation unit), and this address can be an integer multiple of 0x1000.